# Share custom class across Angular application?

Tags: angular

I have a custom class:

```
class Map() {
   constructor(props: Props) {}
}
```

I initialize this class in my bootstrapped component `app.component.ts`:

```
export class AppRootComponentComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() props: Props;
    public map: Map;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.map = new Map(this.props);
    }
}
```

How to share initialized `this.map = new Map` across Angular app? I get properties from outside (Angular Elements approach).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about Angular Elements. But if you want to share a property across your Angular app, there's a few ways. Usually, when we think about property sharing in Angular, we think Inputs or some kind of Service/Store approach.

From your description, I'm getting a "global variable" vibe hahahh...so, I believe the best approach would be using a root provided service to store this property, maybe sharing access/updates to it with a Subject.

Cheers!

Comment: If I use root provided service it is initialized automatically. But I need to initialize manually when I get data from input, and only then share it

Comment: But if you use a BehaviorSubject sharing an undefined value initially, emitting an actual value only when you have this input set, wouldn't it work? Maybe I didn't really understand your need!

Answer (score 0):

You can create behaviourSubject in common component and use it in required component.

Declare as below in service.

```
map = new BehaviorSubject<Map>(null);
```

Create a function in same service :

```
setMap(map) {
this.map.next(map);
}
```

In your component inject the above service in constructor then in ngoninit :

```
this.map = new Map(this.props);
this.sharedService.setMap(this.map);
```

Now, you can access it in any component by injecting abouve service the

```
this.sharedService.map.subscribe(map => {
//your code here
});
```